# Why should we track the inside of the word in K&R Exercise 1-11?

Tags: c, input, character, whitespace

Here is the exercise:

> Write a program that prints its input one word per line.

My solution to this exercise is the following:

```
main() {
    int c; 
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) { 
        if(c == ' ' || c == '\t' ) 
            putchar('\n');
        else
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
}
```

According to this [link](https://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K%26R2_solutions:Chapter_1:Exercise_12)
it is a bad solution, but I'm not sure I understand why.

I would appreciate some help understanding this.

Comment: Perhaps because the question asks you to print a word at a time but you print a char at a time? A word typically consists of more than one character.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, consider what happens when you input `a  b      c`. Or, as one of the comments in the link says, run it with your own .c source file as input.

Comment: Multiple leading, included or trailing whitespace causes blank lines in your output. The solution is to add a simple flag to track whether you are (1) in a word reading characters or (2) between words reading whitespace and only output your `'\n'` when your transition from reading characters to whitespace.An example counting words (applicable here) [Local variables and memory in c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54315165/3422102)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when your input contains more than one newline, tab or space in subsequent order.

Then it always jumps into a new line, although it shouldn't.

The requirement of to "*print one word per line*" is not fulfilled then.

You need to keep an eye on whether the newline, tab or space occurs after a sequence of non-instruction characters or not. So we need a `"STATE"` parameter which documents the current state.

Chrismath's solution covers that:

```
// print input one word per line 

#define IN 1 
#define OUT 0 

int main (void) 
{ 
      int c, state; 
      // start without a word 
      state = OUT; 
         
      while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { 
              // if the char is not blank, tab, newline 
              if (c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n') { 
                      // inside a word 
                      state = IN; 
                      putchar(c); 
              // otherwise char is blank, tab, newline, word ended 
              } 
              else if (state == IN) { 
                      state = OUT; 
                      putchar('\n'); 
              } 
      } 
      return 0;
}
```

The newline is only printed when `state` is `IN` which means at least a word of one character was printed in a line before it get to another one.

Someone could argue that a word wouldn't be a single character, but then we would need an explicit requirement of how many characters at least a word is consisted of, but this isn't provided to the task here, so the one character word is plausible and legit.

Answer (score 2):

After comparing a few answers, the difference between the solution i have written above versus the correct solution in the link in the question is that a newline is not created for each blank, tab or newline character. The correct answer checks whether it has already accounted for a space and output the corresponding newline and doesn't output another newline if there is another space, thus answering the problem of "one word per line"

Comment: Make sure to include in the answer also the corrected code. ;)

Comment: @RobertoCaboni: Code is not needed to answer the question, which is why the code in the question is incorrect, not what correct code is. Learning the lesson to pay attention to the details of the program specification is valuable by itself.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ...nevertheless some code snippets such as _"I would do `this stuff` instead of `this other stuff`"_ would make the answer more complete. It would be required for anyone, and I don't see why it shouldn't be the same for the OP. I'm really happy that the OP _"learned the lesson"_ and I was going to give my upvote. That's why I asked for completeness. ;)